# What is 'hardware cloth' sold as in the UK?

Tags: materials

Some instructions I am following from an American site call for 'hardware cloth'. It's a kind of square wire mesh, that can take weight. I can't find this on any UK sites (the closest I could find is chicken wire, which I expect wouldn't be as strong). Presumably it has a different name. What is it?

[image]

http://www.thesodacanstove.com/pot-support/index.html

Comment: Depending on the size of your burner/pot you can buy a cheap wire bird feeder and take off the ends and cut off a piece to the length you need for the stand; I've done that and then re-fixed the bird feeder ends to the remaining piece to make a mini-feeder!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's also known as welded wire mesh, or woven wire mesh (your picture shows welded not woven mesh).  Stucco netting also might do you.  For supporting a stove chicken wire is probably fine also.